# Perform calculation between adjacent rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the Euclidean distance between 3-dimensional points, and add that distance as an additional column. I tried to loop through the rows, like this:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(list('x'=1:5,'y'=(1:5)^2,'z'=6:10))

for (i in 2:nrow(df1)) {
  df1$diff <- sqrt((df1$x[i,]-df1$x[i-1,])^2 - 
                   (df1$y[i,]-df1$y[i-1,])^2 -
                   (df1$z[i,]-df1$z[i-1,])^2)
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in df1$x[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `sqrt(abs(Reduce('-',lapply(df1, function(x) (x- lag(x, default=x[1]))^2))))` or `c(0, sqrt(abs(Reduce('-',as.data.frame((sapply(df1, diff))^2)))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you are treating `x` as an array-like object when indexing. I.e. you are using `x[row, col]` indexing where you should be using `x[element]`.

You also need to index into `df1$diff` when inserting results into it. And you have the Euclidean distance equation wrong; you need to add up the squared differences, not subtract them.

```
df1 <- data.frame(list(x = 1:5, y = (1:5)^2, z = 6:10))
df1$diff <- NA

for (i in 2:nrow(df1)) {
  df1$diff[i] <- with(df1, sqrt((x[i] - x[i-1])^2 + 
                                (y[i] - y[i-1])^2 +
                                (z[i] - z[i-1])^2))
}

> df1
  x  y  z     diff
1 1  1  6       NA
2 2  4  7 3.316625
3 3  9  8 5.196152
4 4 16  9 7.141428
5 5 25 10 9.110434
```

You don't need the loop for this though, you can rely on R doing element-by-element operations and thus do this in a single step:

```
df1 <- data.frame(list(x = 1:5, y = (1:5)^2, z = 6:10))
df1$diff <- c(NA, sqrt(rowSums((df1[-1, 1:3] - df1[-5, 1:3])^2)))

df1

> df1
  x  y  z     diff
1 1  1  6       NA
2 2  4  7 3.316625
3 3  9  8 5.196152
4 4 16  9 7.141428
5 5 25 10 9.110434
```

You'll probably want to do this with `df1` coerced to a matrix if your real problem is large, as data frames are quite slow.

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df1[, 1:3])
m1 <- cbind(m1, diff = c(NA, sqrt(rowSums((m1[-1, 1:3] - m1[-5, 1:3])^2))))

> m1
     x  y  z     diff
[1,] 1  1  6       NA
[2,] 2  4  7 3.316625
[3,] 3  9  8 5.196152
[4,] 4 16  9 7.141428
[5,] 5 25 10 9.110434
```

You can wrap this into a function using `head()` and `tail()` so you do't need to worry about how many rows the original data has:

```
myEuc <- function(x) {
  if (isdf <- is.data.frame(x)) {
    x <- data.matrix(x)
  }
  dij <- c(NA, sqrt(rowSums((tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1))^2)))
  x <- cbind(x, diff = dij)
  if (isdf) {
    x <- as.data.frame(x)
  }
  x
}

df1 <- data.frame(list(x = 1:5, y = (1:5)^2, z = 6:10))
myEuc(df1)

> myEuc(df1)
     x  y  z     diff
     1  1  6       NA
[2,] 2  4  7 3.316625
[3,] 3  9  8 5.196152
[4,] 4 16  9 7.141428
[5,] 5 25 10 9.110434
```

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for catching my very dumb mistake in the equation.

Comment: Thanks. You can do this without a loop. Give me a second and I'll post simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```
sqrt(Reduce('+',lapply(df1, function(x) (x- lag(x, default=x[1]))^2)))
#[1] 0.000000 3.316625 5.196152 7.141428 9.110434
```

Or

```
c(0,sqrt(rowSums((sapply(df1, diff))^2)))
#[1] 0.000000 3.316625 5.196152 7.141428 9.110434
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new variable has one fewer observations than your data.frame, so you need to add an NA to either the top or the bottom of the vector:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(list('x'=1:5,'y'=(1:5)^2,'z'=6:10))

myVec <- numeric(nrow(df1))
myVec[1] <- NA
for (i in 2:nrow(df1)) {
myVec[i] <- sqrt((df1[i,"x"]-df1[i-1,"x"])^2 + 
                 (df1[i,"y"]-df1[i-1,"y"])^2 +
                 (df1[i,"z"]-df1[i-1,"z"])^2)
}

df1$diff <- myVec
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first part, `myVec <- ...`. I changed "df" to "df1", but get the error "Error in vector(nrow(df1)) : vector: cannot make a vector of mode '5'."

Comment: @Adam_G I think I fixed the "many" typos from my sloppy first round.